# when does dlopen blocks?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, dlopen, shared-objects

sharedlibrary loaded through `LD_PRELOAD`, constructor of the same library calls `dlopen("libc.so.6")`

the problem is `dlopen` takes forever, debugging showes the following
`dlopen` calls __`dlopen` which calls `calloc`, and unknow function `??,` then at last `__GI___pthread_mutex_lock`.

providing unlimited resources before dlopen as I suspected, but doesn't solve the problem.

the problem only happen if LD_PRELOAD is set with sharedlibrary (mentioned above) with target application `Firefox` at Linux any other application works without problems(`dlopen` doesn't block)!

Answer (score 0):

> when does dlopen blocks?

When it needs a lock that is not available for some reason.

> debugging showes

You need *more* debugging. The `dlopen` calls `calloc` which requires a malloc lock. Nothing special about that.

It *must* be that some other thread is holding this malloc lock, and is waiting for your `LD_PRELOAD`ed library to finish its initialization (thus creating a deadlock). You should be able to find that other thread with `(gdb) thread apply all where`.

It may also matter what functions you are trying to interpose in your `LD_PRELOAD`ed library.